# How can I always show two decimal places with jQuery sparklines?

Tags: sparklines

How can I show values with always two decimal numbers in sparkline tooltip?
For example, I want 1.20 to show as "1.20" and not "1.2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found solution:
sparkline has option: tooltipFormat, where you can format tooltip.

```
var sparklineCharts = function(){
    $('#my_id').sparkline(currentMonthArray, sparklineSettings);
  };

var sparklineSettings = {
    type: 'line',
    width: '100%',
    height: '50',
    lineColor: '#1ab394',
    fillColor: 'transparent',
    tooltipFormat: '{{y.2}}'
  };
```